# Installing an executable or MicroPython script on a Pico to run without a computer attached

Tags: pi-pico

I've searched and not found an answer..   I'm proficient in C and Micro-python and developing and running programs is easy enough.

However I can't figure out how I install a program I've written to the Pico so that when I supply it purely power it runs?

With ESP32 devices I would normally flash the program to NVMe ram and configure uboot to run it.

Answer (score 7):

Using Thonny save your MicroPython file to the pico as a file called main.py

Next time you power on the Pico your program should autostart.

See section 4.1.1:

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/pico/raspberry-pi-pico-python-sdk.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Or, if you don't want to use Thonny (I prefer to choose my own development environment), you can use [ampy](https://github.com/scientifichackers/ampy), a command-line tool for micropython boards.

Example usage:

```
ampy -p /dev/ttyACM0 put main.py
```

Note that to auto-run, your Python file needs to be called `main.py`.

Comment: Thanks I use C normally..  Buy I've been playing with micro python on the nano so its nice to know how to auto start it.

Comment: @SimonBanks For C, I think you just build a UF2 binary, and drag that onto the Pico [after booting it in programming mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/rp2040/getting-started/)? I haven't tried C on the Pico yet myself, but I think that's the method.

Comment: @SimonBanks By the way, the Pico also has a single-wire debugging interface (the 3 pads on the short side). I think you can also program it over that interface, but I _really_ haven't researched that yet :)

Answer (score 2):

I met only with failure to have main.py run on the Pico at boot until I realized the file had been saved on the Pico through Thonny WITHOUT the .py extension. Ridiculous, but it may explain why many have had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload a Python script with `ampy` or `rshell` as mentioned in the answers above, one may need to add itself to `dialout` group to be able to upload without sudo. Note re-login is needed for the group change to take effect

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER
```

By default on my Ubuntu, Pico's serial port is owned by `root` user and `dialout` group so an ordinal user cannot access it

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 1 Mar  7 09:57 /dev/ttyACM1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `rshell` instead of `ampy`:

```
python3 -m pip install --user rshell
rshell -p /dev/ttyACM0 --buffer-size 512 cp blink.py /pyboard/main.py
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183596/how-can-you-make-a-micropython-program-on-a-raspberry-pi-pico-autorun/74078142#74078142